# Malformed URL Exception when using jsoup.connect

Tags: java, android

I am using a textwatcher in edittext to validate if a string is a url

```
  if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()) {
```

and this url is passed to asynctask where

```
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                // Connect to the web site
                    document = Jsoup.connect(URLEncoder.encode(URL, "UTF-8"))
                            .userAgent("Mozilla").get();

            }
```

but on typing m.go in edittext i get a malformedURLException:

java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: M.go

am also trying to catch the exception

```
 catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Could you help me with a solution as the app crashes everytime

CompleteLog:

E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: M.go
                                                                      at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:101)
                                                                      at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:43)
                                                                      at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
                                                                      at 
                                                                      at                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: M.go
                                                                      at java.net.URL.(URL.java:589)
                                                                      at java.net.URL.(URL.java:486)
                                                                      at java.net.URL.(URL.java:435)
                                                                      at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:99)
                                                                      at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:43) 
                                                                      at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73) 
                                                                      at 
                                                                      at  
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Comment: where is the complete error log..what is the url...is the url is m.go ?

Comment: Is the url a secret?  I have a feeling it might help with the solution.

Comment: didnt get you, steve?

Comment: Is the url "M.go"?  if so, it needs to be something like "http://M.go".

Comment: yeah but why is  if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()) returns true on "m.go" and url is the

Comment: public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (query.toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                    isValidUrl(query.toString());

Comment: yeah m.go is the url in this case, should i use another way to validate a string if it is a url?

Comment: Check the URL value ..As  steve smith says if the url is "M.go" remove double quotes and run again ..

Comment: there are no double quotes

Comment: also it works well for other URLs, why is m.go identified as a valid URL?, Can you guide me with a better way to validate if a string is a URL or not